# Eclipse compiles only referenced classes (how to setup Intellij to do the same)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a module that has a module dependency called shared which has the majority of my applications code across all applications. There are classes in shared that reference for example the servlet 3.0 API (jar dependency) that are not used in this module among a bunch of other stuff. Intellij looks like it compiles everything in a module, unlike eclipse, including when compiling with maven. With Eclipse, eclipse only compiles files that are imported into the application. Is there a way to change this?

Is there documentation for how eclipse builds projects? How it knows to ignore files in source folders that are not referenced in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA compiles all the classes in the module, it's by design. You can exclude certain classes or directories from compilation in the compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a large module, of which is only a small part is actually used, is probably a bad idea. I'd suggest refactoring your module structure. This does not only solve your problem, it also makes the true dependencies clearer to everybody else.